VBA save file on a Sharepoint
I am attemping to export the workbook/sheet I am working on to a Sharepoint.
Regardless of the object I am trying to save (book/sheet), I am getting an error. "Method 'SaveAs of object '_Workbook' failed "
The SharePoint is outside my organization, but I have been granted access rights to upload and create files there.
Have any of You encountered such difficulties?
Sub ExportSheetToSharePoint()
    Dim wsExport As Worksheet
    Dim wsLogowanie As Worksheet
    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim sharePointURL As String
    Dim sharePointFilePath As String
    Dim part1 As String
    Dim part2 As String
    Dim part3 As String
    Dim wasVeryHidden As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Sharepoin link in 4 parts
    part1 = url1
    part2 = url2
    part3 = url3
    part4 = url4
    
    sharePointURL = part1 & part2 & part3 & part4
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsExport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("export")
    Set wsLogowanie = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Logowanie")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    wasVeryHidden = (wsExport.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden)
    
    If wasVeryHidden Then
        wsExport.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
    
    ' nazwa pliku Logowanie!E10
    fileName = "test" + ".xsls"
    
    
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
    wsExport.Copy Before:=newBook.Sheets(1)
    
  
    If wasVeryHidden Then
        wsExport.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If

    newBook.Sheets("export").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In newBook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "export" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    sharePointFilePath = sharePointURL & fileName
    
**    newBook.SaveAs sharePointFilePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook**
 
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    newBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    MsgBox "Export complete: " & sharePointFilePath
    
    ' Cleanup
    Set newBook = Nothing
    Set wsExport = Nothing
    Set wsLogowanie = Nothing
End Sub


Maybe this article is of any help.

Could you sync the Sharepoint folder to your OneDrive and then use as a local folder?

It might be worth recording a macro of the process, and then checking the path the recording used vs the path you're trying to use above.

Also, while I don't think it will be the cause of the error you've described - you might want to check your file extension on fileName = "test" + ".xsls"

@Darren Bartrup-Cook: If you are syncing one might probably want to use VBA File Tools

@Storax yes I've used that at home, but it doesn't seem to work while I'm at work with an address of https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/documents/general/folders..../filename.xlsx or with https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/site_name/share documents/general/folders..../filename.xlsx  but that's a different question from the OP one.

Study this and then the herein referred link

Please add an example of the value of sharePointFilePath when it fails (obscure the actual site name etc, but do not alter the core structure of the path)
